# R if condition with dates in a loop

Tags: r, loops, date, if-statement

I want to extract a result with a double condition (one of them is with dates) using a loop.
If `touchpoint_type` is equal to `"b"` and `datum [i]` is previous to `datum[i-1]` then multiply by `2` the `indiv_scores[i]` and paste it in `indiv_scores2[i]`.
I attache the code. Apparently there is a problem with `"<"`.

```
id  datum   touchpoint_type indiv_scores    indiv_scores2
1   31.10.2017 05:09    a   1,7 1,7
2   13.10.2017 03:19    b   0,1 0,2
3   10.09.2017 14:26    a   3   3


for (i in 1:length(dataset$id)){
  if (dataset$touchpoint_type[i] == "b"){
    while (as.Date(dataset$datum[i])) < (as.Date(dataset$datum[i-1]))
    {
    dataset$indiv_scores2[i]=dataset$indiv_scores[i]*2
  } } else {
    dataset$indiv_scores2[i]=dataset$indiv_scores[i]
  }
}
```

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: change your while with: while ((as.Date(dataset$datum[i])) < (as.Date(dataset$datum[i-1])))